# Can we able to scale Out Static website hosted in Azure Storage?

Tags: azure

Is that possible or would it able to scale Out a Static website hosting in Azure Storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Scale Out option for a Static website hosting in Azure Storage

You're billed only for the blob storage that your site utilizes and operations costs. For more details on prices for Azure Blob Storage, check out the Azure Blob Storage Pricing Page.
https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/storage/blobs/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website#pricing